# Is it possible for IGGraphEditor to change the curvature of a straight edge by dragging and dropping?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, interactive, igraphm

**Cross-posted at [GitHub](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/issues/127).**

[IGraphM 0.6](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/igraphm-a-mathematica-interface-for-igraph.html) includes IGGraphEditor[], which allows manipulating small graphs interactively.

```
<< IGraphM`
g = CompleteGraph[{2, 2, 2, 2}]
IGGraphEditor[g]
```

In IGGraphEditor, we can easily move vertices of the above graph $K_{2,2,2,2}$, but drawn edges are always straight lines and cannot be altered to be curved.

[image]

For example, I prefer the following layout of $K_{2,2,2,2}$.

[image]

I don't know what's difficult about that? Because many dynamic drawing systems, such as [houseofgraphs](https://houseofgraphs.org/draw_graph) and `layout = interactive` in *Maple* also only provide the ability to draw straight lines.

Comment: Currently edges have automatic shapes only. Should not be hard, only a matter of available time. I will work on updates soon so feel free to create an issue in GH repo but I will try to remember.

Comment: Thanks! I will create an issue in GitHub.